# Why I can't retrieve an object put into the HttpSession in Java?

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

into a method I put an object into the **HttpSession** by this line:

```
req.getSession().setAttribute("docPDF", docPDF);
```

So the previous line put in the session the **docPDF** object (it is a **ByteArrayOutputStream** instance) with the name **docPDF**.

If in the debugger I do:

```
req.getSession().getAttribute("docPDF")
```

I can see this object, so it seems correctly putted into the **HttpSession**.

Then, into another method of my class I have to retrieve it, so I have try in this way:

```
docPDF = (ByteArrayOutputStream) req.getAttribute("docPDF");
```

but the problem is that I obtain that **docPDF** object is **null**.

Why? What I am missing? Maybe it could depend by the fact that this is into another HttpRequest?

How can I correctly retrieve this object that I putted into session?

Thanks

Comment: It should be docPDF = (ByteArrayOutputStream) req.getSession().getAttribute("docPDF"). You're trying to get the attribute from request scope but set it in session scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set a object in Session you have to get from Session only. 
use this code.

```
docPDF = (ByteArrayOutputStream) req.getSession().getAttribute("docPDF")
```